# Python recognizing one directory as module but not another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

My project looks like this:

```
W:\a\lot\of\stuff\Automation
|__ __init__.py
|__ A
|   |_ __init__.py
|   |_ aLotOfFiles.py
|
|__ B
|   |_ __init__.py
|   |_ aLotOfFiles.py
|
|__ C
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ myFile.py
```

where I'm working on `myFile.py`. In it I am using a lot of the files in modules `A` and `B`. When working with Pycharm everything worked perfectly well just by doing

```
from A.someFile import someClass
from B.otherFile import otherClass
```

But then when I finished working on my code and started running it from other places, I started getting import errors being confused I tried the following in interactive python:

```
>import sys
>sys.path.append('W:\\a\\lot\\of\\stuff\\')
>import Automation
# No import errors so far
>import Automation.A
# Still working fine..
>import Automation.B
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named B #Yeah, that's the module name..
```

Now I'm stumped. How can both modules work in Pycharm, be seemingly exactly the same, yet one is imported just fine and the other isn't in the same situation?

Any ideas of how to solve it/what could be causing it/what to check?

Comment: Did you check for case issues (upper/lower)? Maybe the folder is all lowercase but you're importing it in camel case?

Comment: @user2682863 Yep checked that case, wish I was that dumb. But then Pycharm wouldn't have worked, right?

Comment: Is the python interpreter in PyCharm the same one you are using in the other places?

Comment: @jomunculus actually pycharm is 2.7.12 and python is 2.7.8.. Could this cause the issue?

Comment: It is a possibility.  If the 2.7.8 interpreter does not have the UtilTools module that might be the cause.

Comment: @jomunculus Considering I wrote that module, it sounds a bit unlikely..

Comment: Is that module in the path for all Python interpreters?

Comment: @jomunculus I edited the question a bit, maybe now it won't cause confusion..

Comment: do the __init__ modules do anything?

Comment: What is in the root level __init__.py?

Comment: @jomunculus It's empty.. Should there be anything in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Apparently there was an older version of the same workspace somewhere else higher up in the path hierarchy, and it worked when I used modules which were also there, but not when I used new ones...